# Get default post thumbnail from custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

This is default post thumbnail code

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_thumbnail_html' );

function my_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) 
{
    if ( empty( $html ) )
        $html = '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'images/default-thumbnail.png' . '" alt="" />';

    return $html;
}
```

I want to get post thumbnail with this from a custom field

```
/wp-content/plugins/postt/<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'img', true ); ?>.jpg
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Can you be more clear ? You want to get post-thumbnail by which code ?? I did not get you

Comment: Are you using any plugin ? Is this code for slider image ?

Comment: "imdb info box" plugin. no. post featured image